# Window.onscroll - changes history.pushState for 4 compartments

Tags: javascript, if-statement, url, horizontal-scrolling, onscroll

I wanted to creat a script to change my website's link for 4 others compartments. I tried to creat that this way. Is it possiable? If able what should I change? I gave `document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "x!";` just for testing to see effects of my fuction, but that still doesn't work.

```
<script> 
                window.onscroll = function() {testscrollFunction()};
                    function testscrollFunction() {
                        var scrollPosition =  document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                        if (scrollPosition >= 0 && scrollPosition <= 400)
                            {
                            history.pushState({}, null, "index.html#1");
                            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "1!";
                            }
                        if (scrollPosition >= 401 && scrollPosition <= 600)
                            {
                            history.pushState({}, null, "index.html#2");
                            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "2!";
                            }
                        if (scrollPosition >= 601 && scrollPosition <= 800)
                            {
                            history.pushState({}, null, "index.html#3");
                            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "3!";
                            }
                    }
                </script>
```

Same way I have done other script (for button which can scroll to top and shows at height higher than 40) and it works. Can't I have 2 times window.onscroll functions?

Comment: Is it really your intention to actually add history entries on scroll, or do you only need a URL change?

Comment: I wanted add history entries on scroll. Skip reloading of website. And it works with a Scrolling Script based at #es. So need exactly for example history.pushState({}, null, "index.html#newsletter");.